# The responsive mobile site's top-bar dropdowns are missing related links in each one's header

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, 10k-tools, responsive-design

I've got the [access to moderator tools](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege here on Meta SE, and the review queues dropdown ordinarily features the "tools" and "all queues" links that allow quickly hopping to their related pages. This is how they look on the desktop web page:

[image: Image of the desktop's review queues dropdown header, which has the all queues and tools links]

On the responsive site, I'm no longer seeing those two links available to me:

[image: Image of the responsive site's review queues dropdown, now missing the tools and all queues links]

I pretty frequently would open up the tools link to have a look at recently closed/deleted questions throughout the day, and was quite surprised when that flow was interrupted with those links suddenly disappearing from this view.

Additionally, the Achievements dropdown typically features "privileges" and "badges" links. Here's how that looks on the desktop site:

[image: Image of the achievements dropdown, includes the privileges and badges links]

However these are also missing in the responsive mobile design. Here's how that looks:

[image: Image of the achievements dropdown on the responsive mobile design site, with the related links in the top part of it missing]

It's now much more difficult to hop to the privileges list, and it's actually impossible to hop to /tools from the responsive design without digging all the way to the help center and using some links in the description for it.

The same goes for the inbox's "all items" link. On desktop:

[image: Inbox dropdown view on desktop site]

And on the responsive mobile view:

[image: Inbox dropdown view on responsive mobile site, without the all items button]

Could we re-add those links?

**Phone info:**

- Google Pixel 3a
- Chrome, ver. 92.0.4515.131

Comment: The Tools are still available on the [all queues page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review) (which is a little harder to find, now that the "all queues" link is missing from the Pulldown). Also broken is the (JavaScript?) [link to "Learn More" on the "Stats" and "History" tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdOqt.png), but not on the "Review tasks" tab; where it opens the popup help correctly.

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [Please \*\*NEVER\*\* remove clickable items in narrow displays](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410852/4642212).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for removing those links! It was a bug introduced in our march toward deprecating mobile views. We have a fix on the way!